# Dual booting (Ubuntu over Windows) directly to Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, boot-repair

**Problem Case:** Dual booting with Ubuntu (efi/gpt scheme) over Windows (efi/gpt scheme) and My HP pavilion is booting directly to Windows 10.

**Details:**

Previously installed Windows 10 with UEFI, fast start-up, secure boot enabled.

Later installed Ubuntu (GPT partition scheme for Uefi computers and chose Install Ubuntu alongside Windows)

Installation was successful  and after a restart, Computer booted successfully into Ubuntu.

But Ubuntu was unable to access Windows (C drive partition), and suggested to disable fast-startup, so I disabled Fast start-up in Windows. After shutdown and power up, computer is booted directly to Windows 10. Tried many times, but every-time unable to choose OS.

strangely, **EasyBCD** showing Windows 10 as the only installed OS.

Enabled fast start-up in Windows 10 again but in vain.

Did a boot repair using Ubuntu Live USB [[as explained here]](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Ran these commands (one by one)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

after third command it gave error as **'no boot-repair found'**

This was never a case with Ubuntu over Windows 7.

Is it because Windows 10 is installed with efi/gpt scheme?

What about following combination (Dual boot with Ubuntu over Windows 10).
Which of these cases is best for dual booting to prevent this problem.

1. Windows (MBR scheme) and Ubuntu (MBR scheme)
2. Windows (efi/gpt scheme) and Ubuntu (efi/gpt scheme) [**my problem case**]
3. Windows (efi/gpt scheme) and Ubuntu (MBR)

Comment: First, disable fast startup. It doesn't make a worthwile difference anyway, and it needs to be off for a working dual-boot setup. Second, EasyBCD purposefully ignores Linux. What you need is to have the right boot device **in BIOS**. Enter your BIOS at startup, choose ubuntu, let it boot from there. Than you'll get grub to choose windows or ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, I disabled fast startup, still booting directly to Windows & there is no option in BIOS to choose Ubuntu to boot..Bios>System Configuration>Boot Options>Uefi Boot Order>OS boot manager is the top selected device.

Comment: Your third command line should have been `sudo apt-get -y install boot-repair && sudo boot-repair`. Your  `boot-repair` was never run. Run it with sudo. Then reboot and choose boot order sequence at boot with F8 or  F12 , whatever your laptop says. Choose ubuntu.

Comment: After changing the third command, Terminal is still throwing the same error "E: Unable to locate package boot repair"

Comment: You didn't install it? I see now that this step is missing from you lines. A ppa just adds the packages **available**. You need to install it with `apt install boot-repair` before running the third line. I use `sudo apt update && sudo apt install boot-repair` in one line to avoid this issue.

Comment: I appreciate your prompt reply, but it is still throwing the same error "unable to locate...".It was never the case with Windows 7.Was it because I used this combination: Windows (MBR scheme) and Ubuntu (MBR scheme).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to disable **Secure boot** in the BIOS first. Install Windows 10 and then Install Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried to disable secure boot but nothing helps.But you disabled it prior to any OS installation and I am doing it now.

Comment: Yes, change the secure boot BEFORE installing any of the OSes.

Comment: @warhansen that does not make a lot of sense. just installing a bootloader _after_ disabling secure boot should do it as well.